# How to define a map of SqlParameter specifing the SqlType in grovvy?

Tags: spring, groovy, spring-jdbc

I want to create a list of parameter using the constructor MapSqlParameterSource that take a map as input.

Only thing is I don't know how to write a map that will tell MapSqlParameterSource not only ID and Value, but also SqlType.

```
id = 1
desc = "Description"

insertSql = "INSERT INTO table(id,desc) VALUES (:idCode,:descCode)"

SqlParameterSource mapParam = new MapSqlParameterSource([idCode: id, descCode: desc])
```

In this way I can create the SqlParameterSource, but I can't specify directly the SqlTypes, and I got in one of the test an exception:

```
oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleSql.computeBasicInfo(OracleSql.java:950)
oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleSql.getSqlKind(OracleSql.java:623)
oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.<init>(OraclePreparedStatement.java:1212)
oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.<init>(T4CPreparedStatement.java:28)
oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.allocatePreparedStatement(T4CDriverExtension.java:68)
oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.prepareStatement(PhysicalConnection.java:3140)
oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.prepareStatement(PhysicalConnection.java:3042)
oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.prepareStatement(PhysicalConnection.java:6022)
```

That I'm assuming means that couldn't find the SqlType. Do you agree with my assumption and do you have a solution that is not something like this?

```
mapParam = new MapSqlParameterSource()

mapParam.addValue("idCode", stock, Types.NUMBER)
mapParam.addValue("descCode", stockType, Types.VARCHAR)
```

Comment: What's the actual exception? That's a partial stacktrace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try wrapping the value in an SqlParameterValue object using the [SqlParameterValue(int sqlType, Object value) constructor](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/SqlParameterValue.html#SqlParameterValue-int-java.lang.Object-)